# Why does my program generate LdrpLoaderLock deadlock with owning thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, deadlock

I develop a c++ application that I have been working on for years. We recently added some 4 processor test machines to our test lab.

After doing that we found that a specific test under load intermittently results in a `LdrpLoaderLock` deadlock with the owning thread no longer running. The owning thread id is usually numerically suggestive as a likely thread id extrapolated from the running threads and the lock memory structure doesn't look corrupt.

I have not got this issue in a debugger. I am just able to look at it after it happens. I started logging all the threads I am creating and I don't see the problem thread id in there. That might not be meaningful though because it is possible the logging wouldn't work after the deadlock occurs. I think I need a way to track thread creation and entry points so I can figure out which thread is doing this. Any help is appreciated.

From windbg

```
0:000> !locks
CritSec ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock+0 at 775d20c0
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          5
RecursionCount     2
OwningThread       f38
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    5
*** Locked
```

Scanned 805 critical sections

```
0:000> !threads
Index   TID
0   00000ab8
1   000008cc
2   00000e68
3   0000134c
4   00000c44
5   000011a0
6   00000f18
7   00000908
8   00001084
9   00000f08
10  00001098
11  00001010
12  00000d40
13  0000135c
```

Total VM consumed by thread stacks 0x031cf000

```
0:000> d 775d20c0
775d20c0  60 43 5d 77 ea ff ff ff-02 00 00 00 38 0f 00 00  `C]w........8...
775d20d0  ac 04 00 00 00 00 00 00-40 43 5d 77 ff ff ff ff  ........@C]w....
775d20e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  ................
775d20f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
775d2100  00 49 5d 77 ff ff ff ff-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .I]w............
775d2110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
775d2120  20 49 5d 77 ff ff ff ff-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   I]w............
775d2130  00 00 00 00 a0 0f 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

Comment: If the owner thread no longer exists, then it's possible that somebody called `TerminateThread` on it.

Comment: I have removed all calls to TerminateThread from my code. There was only one. My code has no DllMains. I do have one Dll I am linked to but it doesn't have one. I am use several com DLLs which I am sure have DllMains I have the source code for some of them. Is there something I should look for in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raymond Chen was correct. I am calling a third party com component. It was creating a thread and then calling TerminateThread in the destructor. Fortunately I had a source license or I would have been at a loss forever. commenting out the TerminateThread call in that destructor and rebuilding fixed my problem. Now to get the 3rd party to fix their code.